# access values returned by json_decode() in laravel 5.2 blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using 3rd party api in my laravel 5.2 project.

I have installed guzzle to do so.

```
  public function getmovie(Request $request)
{
    $client= new Client();


    $movieurl="http://api.cinemalytics.com/v1/movie/title/?value=madaari&auth_token=<token>";
    $movie=json_decode($client->request('GET',$movieurl)->getBody(),true);

    return $movie[0]['OriginalTitle'];


}
```

Above API code in controller function returns correct data, no problem but when I return view and send $movie to it then in blade I am facing problem accessing the values of $movie

```
 public function getmovie(Request $request)
 {
      $client= new Client();
      $movieurl="http://api.cinemalytics.com/v1/movie/title/?value=madaari&auth_token=<token>";
      $movie=json_decode($client->request('GET',$movieurl)->getBody(),true);

      return view('admin.loadmovie',compact('movie'));
 }
```

In views I am accessing it as

```
 <div class="form-group  margin-top-20">
      <label class="control-label col-md-3">Movie Title
           <span class="required" aria-required="true"> * </span>
      </label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
           <div class="input-icon right">
                <i class="fa"></i>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="movie_title" value="{{ $movie[0]['OriginalTitle'] }}"> 
          </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

It's giving me error message i.e Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Can you add the whole method from where you load this view?

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: Just for debugging, try using var_dump($movie) to check if the movie variable holds the required data and format.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should check if the API returns data, not assume you'll always have a successful response.

You get *Trying to get property of non-object* because in `json_decode()` the second parameter is converting the JSON to associative array. So you either remove the *true* or you access it as array.

Comment: I have checked that API is returning data properly, if I remove true from json_decode() , and try to access value as $movie->OriginalTitle , even then I am getting error, I am confused what to do